# nginx error_page not redirecting with basic setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am running a rails app with the standard 500.html message and in my nginx.conf I have:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    root ~/Projects/rails/localstyling;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

    location @unicorn {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

I have tried adding `proxy_intercept_message;` just above the error_page section but it's not working.  I cannot get nginx to stop serving its own 500 error pages.

Comment: I can't get what do you want

Comment: I want it to server the /500.html in my Rails App root folder but instead nginx is showing its own 500 error page.

Comment: Your `root` directive is incorrect. You should use absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    root <HOME DIRECTORY>/Projects/rails/localstyling;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

    location @unicorn {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```